# Как поставить переменную в функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброе утро! Возникла проблема - как мне передать переменную, назначенную в другой функции в нужную функцию? Концепт следующий - человек вводит свое ФИО. После этого, бот проверяет его наличие в БД. Если фамилия есть - все ок. Но если нет - задача по занесению человека в бд заносится в другую функцию. Вопрос - как передать фио в другую функцию, если переменная с ФИО лежит в другой функции?

Код:

```py
    cur = await conn.cursor()
    teled = message.from_user.id
    sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE teleid=(%s)"
    await cur.execute(sql, (teled))
    row = await cur.fetchone()
    if row is not None:
        name = row[0]
        await Form.name.set()
        async with state.proxy() as id:
            id = teled
        await message.answer("✅ Ваши данные имеются в базе данных. Можно приступать к оплате!", reply_markup=next)
        await Form.next()


@dp.message_handler(row is None, state=Form.name) #<---- тут и возникает мелкая проблема. Если row - none, то необходимо запустить следующую функцию
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
```

Я начинающий практикант, не бейте сильно за тупость

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете просто запустить функцию с уже переданной в нее переменной, например:
`function(your_variable)`, а в в функции `function` (при создании), добавить переменную которая она будет принимать.

наглядно:

```
def function(your_variable):
    pass
    # your code is here ;)

def checking():
    database = ["monkey8", "admin"]
    user_name = input("username ")
    if user_name in database:
        print("Все отлично, вы зарегистрированы")    
    else:
        function(user_name)
        # тут происходит код или заупскается функция, в случае которой пользователя в списке нет
```

Просто запускайте функцию с уже переданной в нее переменной. В таком случае при запуске функции `checking` переменная `user_name` будет переданна в `function`, если она не состоит в списке `database`

в вашем случае достаточно просто добавить в код else.